# How can I remove my app's in-app purchase while leaving premium functionality intact

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have an iPhone app with an existing IAP option.  I'd like to remove the in-app purchase requirement completely while still providing the premium content.  Basically I'd like to replace the "BUY" button with a "GET STARTED" button and go on from there :-)  Is there a "best way" to strip out (overwrite, redirect, etc) the IAP code (objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would expect that premium functionality in the code isn't coupled with IAP. So, basically you substitute logic for receipt checking with your new use case.
So, I recon, the best way will be throw away IAP code and write new functions.